# How to enable code hinting for CSS on Sublime Text 2?

Tags: html, css

I've just started learning HTML and CSS. While watching a tutorial, I noticed that when he has only typed in a few letters of the command, sublime displays a list of possible code hints that he might've been trying to type. When I do that, it only provided hints for things like sans-serif, etc but there is no list that comes of all the possible fonts like it did for the instructor. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get hinting you have to save your file with the extension and ST2 will be able to hint you correctly ;)

Try [this link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html)

Comment: I saved them with the correct file extensions but ST2 is still not providing code hints as thoroughly as it should :(

Comment: And what's the language your using?